# Python-twitter API help

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, python-twitter

I have just started using the python-twitter API and it requires me to register the app for the authorization using OAuth.

But when i register with twitter it asks for a Application website.

Now the app I am creating is very basic I don't wish to share as I am doing this just for learning purposes and I don't have website.

So what do I do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already read this?

[Twitter REST API Method: oauth authorize](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554726/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-oauth-authorize)

and from there this:

[Authentication](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554643/Authentication)

> Desktop Clients
>
> The traditional OAuth flow for desktop
>   clients can be cumbersome. We've
>   created a PIN-based experience for
>   destkop clients that use the following
>   flow:
>
> 1. The application uses
>      oauth/request_token to obtain a
>      request token from twitter.com.
> 2. The application directs the user to oauth/authorize on twitter.com.
> 3. After obtaining approval from the user, a prompt on twitter.com will
>      display a 7 digit PIN.
> 4. The user is instructed to copy this PIN and return to the appliction.
> 5. The application will prompt the user to enter the PIN from step 4.
> 6. The application uses the PIN as the value for the oauth_verifier
>      parameter in a call to
>      oauth/access_token which will verify
>      the PIN and exchange a request_token
>      for an access_token.
> 7. Twitter will return an access_token for the application to
>      generate subsequent OAuth signatures.